# Reuse jQuery function for Read More Button

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a jQuery function like so:

```
 var readMore = jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "Read More") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $(".text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $("#toggle").text("Read More");
      $(".text").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

Now, this function clearly performs read-more button behaviour and works fine. However, there is a slight problem. I want to be able to reuse this function for multiple buttons and text on one page, this is my aim but currently it's only performing the function on one section of text. I've heard that I also won't be able to use ID's for this, with `#toggle`, and the reason being is because 
 "I can't reuse id's, I'll need to convert it to a class."

The function is used in HTML like so:

```
Quisque interdum accumsan metus, at iaculis libero vestibulum vel. <span class="text">Sed dapibus mollis justo, sit amet efficitur tortor laoreet et. In risus sapien, eleifend eget ullamcorper vel, sodales a odio. Phasellus ultricies volutpat luctus.</span>
<button class="button jkit-btn-inverse" id="toggle">Read More</button>
```

The `<span class="text">` is where the text cuts off and hides everything inside that span for the read-more function to make it appear after pressing the button. I can use this in one area, just not in multiple areas.

How would I go about reusing this function?

Edit:

Regarding the first answer, replacing all of the ID's with class does work, however, I can only use it in one area. If I try to use it in another area with another paragraph and another button, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ID` To `Class` same to `HTML Code`

HTML

```
<div class="section">
        Quisque interdum accumsan metus, at iaculis libero vestibulum vel. <span class="text">Sed dapibus mollis justo, sit amet efficitur tortor laoreet et. In risus sapien, eleifend eget ullamcorper vel, sodales a odio. Phasellus ultricies volutpat luctus.</span>
        <button class="button jkit-btn-inverse toggle">Read More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Quisque interdum accumsan metus, at iaculis libero vestibulum vel. <span class="text">Sed dapibus mollis justo, sit amet efficitur tortor laoreet et. In risus sapien, eleifend eget ullamcorper vel, sodales a odio. Phasellus ultricies volutpat luctus.</span>
        <button class="button jkit-btn-inverse toggle">Read More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Quisque interdum accumsan metus, at iaculis libero vestibulum vel. <span class="text">Sed dapibus mollis justo, sit amet efficitur tortor laoreet et. In risus sapien, eleifend eget ullamcorper vel, sodales a odio. Phasellus ultricies volutpat luctus.</span>
        <button class="button jkit-btn-inverse toggle">Read More</button>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
var readMore = jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            $(".section .toggle").click(function () {
                var elem = $(this).text();
                if (elem == "Read More") {
                    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
                    $(this).text("Read Less");
                    $(this).parent().find('.text').slideDown();
                } else {
                    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
                    $(this).text("Read More");
                    $(this).parent().find('.text').slideUp();
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS

```
 span.text {
            display: none;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4jfzdwLb/

Comment: Edit: Sorry, this doesn't work at all and I've already tried this.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Days of stress and it was this simple. Thanks.